# Equilibrium and general solution of this polynomial non linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

I'm trying to find the equilibrium points and the general solution of this non-linear polynomial ODE, but I can't find a substitution that works....

$$
\left(\frac{du}{d\phi} \right)^{2} = 2Mu^{3} - u^{2} + \frac{1}{D^{2}} \,\, ,
$$

where $M,D \in \mathbb{R}$. If there is some good book in solving this, please indicate me!

Thank is advance!

Comment: take a square root of both sides and you get an ode which can be solved by separation of variables

Comment: What about the equilibrium solutions? I'm interested in investigate the possible bifurcations of this system. @Vasya

Comment: To find equilibrium solutions you need to set derivative equal to zero and find solutions of the resulting cubic equation.